# JSON parsin error - How I using CodingKeys Swift parse a dynamic key?

Tags: json, swift

My code

```
struct Functionality: Codable {
  let subCod: String?
  let parentFunctionality: String?
  let transaccional: String?
  let permissions: MyModel?

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case subCod
    case parentFunctionality
    case transaccional
    case "permissions" -> dynamic key
  }
```

I need to parse a JSON where, in place of permission, there will be a dynamic key. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Something like [String: MyModel] perhaps but there is so little information here.

Comment: do you mean there's a property whose name is different every time (and not definable)? or a property whose name could be one of the known names (i.e. maybe there's dozen of names, but it will be one of them)?

Comment: You could apply a custom `KeyDecodingStrategy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift decode json when one property name / key is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74945176/swift-decode-json-when-one-property-name-key-is-dynamic)